# How can I change the formatting of my date within my script, would like it to show dd/mm/yyyy only

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, date-formatting

```
function reminder() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  var data = sh.getDataRange().getValues()
  var d = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i=1;i<data.length;i++){
    if (data[i][4]<=new Date(d+7*24*60*60*1000) && data[i][4]>=new Date(d+5*24*60*60*1000) && data[i][6]==''){
      MailApp.sendEmail({to:data[i][3],
        subject: 'Reminder Process Update Required in 1 week',
        htmlBody: 'Hello '+data[i][1]+' The page for '+data[i][0]+' is due to review on '+data[i][4]+' Please review the content and contact the team before its due date if amendments are required.'
      })
      sh.getRange(i+1,7).setValue('sent')
    }
    else if (data[i][4]<=new Date(d+30*24*60*60*1000)  && data[i][4]>=new Date(d+28*24*60*60*1000)  && data[i][5]==''){
      MailApp.sendEmail({to:data[i][3],
        subject: 'Reminder Process Update Required in 1 month',
        htmlBody: 'Hello '+data[i][1]+' The page for '+data[i][0]+' is due to review on '+data[i][4]+' Please review the content and contact the team before its due date if amendments are required.'
      })
      sh.getRange(i+1,6).setValue('sent')
    }
  }
}
```

How can I change the date formatting in my script, It is currently generating an automated email however the date is being formatted and showing the Time as well as (Eastern Standard Time) I would like it to only show the date without the time included.

Comment: You mean like `\`${d.getDate()}/${d.getMonth() + 1}/${d.getFullYear()}\``?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a format function like

```
function formatDate(d) {
  return `${String(d.getDate()).padStart(2, '0')}/${String(d.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0')}/${d.getFullYear()}`;
}
```

Example:

```js
function formatDate(d) {
  return `${String(d.getDate()).padStart(2, '0')}/${String(d.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0')}/${d.getFullYear()}`;
}

const i = 0;
const data = [['Client', 'Recipient',,, new Date()]];
console.log('Hello '+data[i][1]+' The page for '+data[i][0]+' is due to review on '+formatDate(data[i][4])+' Please review the content and contact the team before its due date if amendments are required.');
```

Comment: So currently in my script '+data[i][4]+ is pulling the date from the sheet on the html.body line. How could I amend that to then format the date as dd/mm/yyyy. Could I simply copy and paste any of the above into my code without any amendments and would this run/work

Comment: @Raj You have to copy the function and then you can format the date with `formatDate(data[i][4])` in `htmlBody`

Answer (score 0):

call this function where you need formatted date.

```
function formatDate(date) {
    var d = new Date(date),
        month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = '' + d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear();

    if (month.length < 2) 
        month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) 
        day = '0' + day;

    return [ day, month, year].join('/');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While there are other ways to format a date, a more direct, Apps Script-based way to do this is using `Utilities.formatDate`:

```
const formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(data[i][4], Session.getTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Just add this line right before sending the email and replace `data[i][4]` with `formattedDate` in the `htmlBody`.

#### Reference:

- [Utilities.formatDate](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format)